# Ionic TextFile Clear Button Keyboard Behavior iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a text input in my Ionic application that has 2 buttons in the same span.  The first button is used to conduct a search and the second is used to clear the text input.  I'm seeing odd behavior when I tap the clear button, the text input is cleared and the keyboard reappears but the text field does not have focus.

Can anyone help so that I can make sure the text input still has focus after clearing the text?  Thank you.

```html
<form class="list">
  <span class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper address-label" name="addressLabel">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon" ng-show="!address.length"></i>
      <input type="text" class="address-input" placeholder="Search By Address" ng-model="address" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" id="button1" class="button button-small custom-btn ion-search" ng-click="search(address)" ng-show="address.length"></button>
    <button ng-click="address = ''" class="button button-small custom-btn ion-close-round" ng-show="address.length"></button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using Ionic v1? your code is working differently when I add it in iOS platform in the Ionic. when I click the clear the text field clears and keyboard dismiss

Comment: I am using version 1.7.14.  Are you using Version 2?  Thanks.

Comment: no , I am using 1.7.11, but in the Ionic v2, they have improved search bar which gives you default cancel button, i am updating the version and let you know if i find anything

Comment: I have noticed that if I move the Clear button out of the <span> the same behavior is not happening and it will dismiss the keyboard when pressing the button.

Comment: so does that solve the issue?, as in the 1.7.14 also i am having the same working as you are currently getting with different span

Comment: Not yet unfortunately.  I may need to tweak the layout but it offers a possible  approach.  I'd really like to have the text input gain focus after pressing the clear button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post from the ionic framework forums. Seems like this would work and give you a more native look and feel.

```
<div class="list list-inset">
   <div class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="mail stop"
            name="mail_stop_name"
      >
      <i class="icon ion-ios-close placeholder-icon"
         data-tap-disabled="true"  on-touch="formData.mail_stop_name = ''"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ref: 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/clear-button-inside-input-causes-input-to-loose-focus/17016